# Django-allauth login/signup in one view

Tags: django, django-views, django-allauth

I am working on a django project and i would like to have one website page called login_register where the user can see the login form and click on a button to change that form to the sign up form using javascript.

So i am stuck on finding out how to make this work and have login and signup forms on one page.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why? What have you tried?

Comment: i didn't try anything that worked actually, i have the idea of creating a class based view with subclassing from both allauth's login and signup views but m still trying to find out how it'll work

Answer (score -1):

You're basically overthinking it.

The trick is not to subclass anything. To render the forms, you just need a view that passes both form instances to a template. The template then has to surround each form with a form tag and the form tag can have ... drumroll ... an action attribute.

You fill the action attribute with `{% url "account_login" %}` and `{% url "account_signup" %}` respectively and everything will work out just fine.

Since you can't see how things should be working top-down, go bottom-up: start coding the template, then the view and using `get_context_data()` pass the various forms to the template.

Comment: but i think only using the form as you mentioned will not keep the social login option, also i want that the social login option will be available with the sign up form

Comment: Where did I say one form? You split rendering the forms from processing the forms. The processing is done by the built-in sign-up and login views. You just render them both, 3 - 4- 5 forms, whatever in one different view and for each form set the action url to the built-in views. Views and forms are loosely coupled. You're free to decouple them.